# Unable to create converter for java.util.List Retrofit 2.0.0-beta2

Tags: java, android, retrofit

I'm just doing a GET request, but I'm getting this error:

> java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.yomac_000.chargingpoint/com.example.yomac_000.chargingpoint.AllStores}: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unable to create converter for java.util.List

And it's because of this line of code:

```
Call<List<Store>> call = subpriseAPI.listStores(response);
```

So I had tried with this line of code to see what type it is:

```
System.out.println(subpriseAPI.listStores(response).getClass().toString());
```

But then I get the same error so it doesn't let me know what type it is. Here below you can see my code.

StoreService.java:

```
public class StoreService {

    public static final String BASE_URL = "http://getairport.com/subprise/";
    Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
            .build();

    SubpriseAPI subpriseAPI = retrofit.create(SubpriseAPI.class);
    String response = "";

    public List<Store> getSubprises() {

        Call<List<Store>> call = subpriseAPI.listStores(response);

        try {
            List<Store> listStores = call.execute().body();

            System.out.println("liststore "+ listStores.iterator().next());
            return listStores;
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // handle errors
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

SubpriseAPI.java:

```
public interface SubpriseAPI {
    @GET("api/locations/get")
    Call<List<Store>> listStores(@Path("store") String store);
}
```

Store.java:

```
public class Store {
    String name;
}
```

I'm using Retrofit version 2.0.0-beta2.

Comment: I also had this problem and I asked Retrofit developers to make the error more meaningful here https://github.com/square/retrofit/issues/1774.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

In the 2+ version you need to inform the Converter

> CONVERTERS
>
> By default, Retrofit can only deserialize HTTP bodies into OkHttp's
>   ResponseBody type and it can only accept its RequestBody type for
>   @Body.
>
> Converters can be added to support other types. Six sibling modules
>   adapt popular serialization libraries for your convenience.
>
> Gson: com.squareup.retrofit:converter-gson Jackson: com.squareup.retrofit:converter-jackson
>   Moshi: com.squareup.retrofit:converter-moshi
>   Protobuf: com.squareup.retrofit:converter-protobuf
>   Wire: com.squareup.retrofit:converter-wire
>   Simple XML: com.squareup.retrofit:converter-simplexml

```
// Square libs, consume Rest API
compile 'com.squareup.retrofit:retrofit:2.0.0-beta1'
compile 'com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp:2.4.0'
compile 'com.squareup.retrofit:converter-gson:2.0.0-beta1'
```

So,

```
String baseUrl = "" ;
Retrofit client = new Retrofit.Builder()
    .baseUrl(baseUrl)
    .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
    .build();
```

Comment: This one worked for me `compile 'com.squareup.retrofit:converter-gson:2.0.0-beta2'`

Comment: also you can add it by this     compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.0.0'

Comment: You also need to pass the Moshi instance into the MoshiConverterFactory.create() method if you are using custom adapters

Answer (score 4):

```
public interface SubpriseAPI {
     @GET("api/locations/get")
     Call<List<Store>> listStores(@Path("store") String store);
}
```

you declared a `@Path` called store, so in your `@GET` annotation retrofit is expecting to find the placeholder for the substitution. E.g.

```
@GET("api/locations/{store}")
Call<List<Store>> listStores(@Path("store") String store);
```