# Retrofit with Logansquare Unable to create converter for java.util.ArrayList

Tags: android, arraylist, retrofit, logan-square

I am using Retrofit 2 with Logansquare converter. Here's my call:

    `@GET("v1/account/notification/{accountId}")
    Call<ArrayList<Message>> getUnreadMessages(@Path("accountId") String accountId);`

And here's the crash log message:

`Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unable to create converter for java.util.ArrayList<com.example.dataModels.Message>`

My Message class:

```
@JsonObject
public class Message {

    @JsonField
    public String _id;
    @JsonField
    public String message;
    @JsonField
    public String createdAt;

    public Message() {
    }
}
```

Is there a solution to this? Please help.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Unable to create converter for java.util.List Retrofit 2.0.0-beta2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34315499/unable-to-create-converter-for-java-util-list-retrofit-2-0-0-beta2)

Comment: No. Unfortunately, that solution doesn't work for me. I already have ConverterFactory added to my Retrofit instance.